# how to show image from url facebook application?

Tags: image, url, facebook, cakephp

on googling i found this code facebook.fbml.refreshImgSrc('imgURL')

how to use this code with cakephp..

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [core helper in cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/835/image)

```
<?php echo $html->image('http://example.com/cake_logo.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'))?>
```

will output

```
<img src="http://example.com/cake_logo.png" alt="CakePHP" />
```

You can get more details about this in the cook.I think it should be helpful.

Comment: @udhaya,this is just an example,and absolute path can be used in it too.see update...